# C# how do I prevent tab key press when textbox is empty

Tags: c#, winforms

Below code is work fine but how can I stop tab key when my textbox.text is empty how I put my if logic in ProcessCmdKey event?

```
bool a = true;
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Tab && !a)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: You can't just do if (keyData == Keys.Tab && string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text))?

Comment: Thanks Scottie you give me a right answer. I appreciate your concern.

Comment: Re-posted as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override [ProcessTabKey()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.processtabkey?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Form_ProcessTabKey_System_Boolean_) and return true if you want to suppress Tab movement.  You could check [this.ActiveControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol?view=netcore-3.1) if you want it to work only for TextBoxes.

Here's a version that only suppresses Tab for those TextBoxes listed in the "SelectTextBoxes" List:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SelectTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>() { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3 }; // list the textboxes here
    }

    private List<TextBox> SelectTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>(); 

    protected override bool ProcessTabKey(bool forward)
    {
        Control ctl = this.ActiveControl;
        if (ctl != null && ctl is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)ctl;
            if (SelectTextBoxes.Contains(tb) && tb.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return base.ProcessTabKey(forward); // process TAB key as normal
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes I have many textBoxes in my Form but I want to validate selected text Boxes to prevent tab key. and Your code is not work in my project. By using your code I still press tab key and next control was selected. In next comment I show you my custom code which I was failed to update on selected textBoxes.

Comment: protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            Control ctl = this.ActiveControl;
            if (keyData == Keys.Tab && string.IsNullOrEmpty(ctl.Text))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }

Comment: If you able to update my above code for my selected text Boxes then I accept your answer.

Comment: you did it man. Thanks for your time and concern. your code is finally worked for me as I needed. Thanks A lot.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the code to the following:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Tab && string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text))
        return true;

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```